# The real meaning of "傲嬌"

Tags: translation, meaning, vocabulary, usage, meaning-in-context

Until recently, I have known the meaning of this word as described on the [wiki](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%82%B2%E5%AC%8C) page. I thought it is used to refer to people, particularly female, who are cold on the outside and hot, as in intimate, on the inside; I assumed that it is a compliment. Then, I read it in the following context and was confused:

> 一定要傲嬌炫富？xxx看看那些溫良恭儉讓的貴婦

The negative connotation of word is pretty obvious and probably does not have the meaning described in the wiki page. What does this word mean then?

By the way, is this a formal word? I supposed it is only used in colloquial context, but I have seen it various times on the news.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this case "傲嬌" 's "嬌" may be assimilated to the meaning in "溫室裡的花朵" or "嬌貴", and hence the negative connotation, IMHO.

Comment: This is not where the word should be used. The poster is actually abusing the word.

Comment: A word comes from JP animation and companies with "双马尾", indicating some typical animation leading roles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

傲嬌 is a word from Japanese animation and just used in the Internet.

> 傲娇指的是这样一种性格：
>
> 表面上对陌生人/喜欢的人很冷淡或趾高气昂，即展现出“傲”的一面，而一旦关系突破某一好感度/耻度界限后，或者遭遇某种契机(特殊事件)的时候，就会突然变得害羞、娇俏可人，即表现出“娇”的一面。

ref : [http://zh.moegirl.org/傲娇](http://zh.moegirl.org/%E5%82%B2%E5%A8%87)

At most time, a person who is 傲嬌, means he/she is 傲 at first and then 嬌 when he/she met someone he/she link.

For your context, I think it's a not standard usage of this word and may just means 傲 only.

Comment: +1 for "a word from Japanese"